# How was Harry supposed to reply to his first year's letter from Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter

As a follow-up of [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/151200/how-did-they-know-harry-hadnt-read-the-first-letter) (quote stolen from the [answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/151242/40429) with bolded text from me)

> Dear Mr Potter, We are pleased to inform you that you have a place at
>   Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry. Please find enclosed a
>   list of all necessary books and equipment. Term begins on 1 September.
>   **We await your owl by no later than 31 July**. Yours sincerely, Minerva
>   McGonagall Deputy Headmistress

Assuming that the Dursleys were not complete jerks - they just explain Harry that he is a wizard and stuff.

All good and nice but ... how is Harry supposed to get an owl and answer? The Dursleys cannot buy him one even if they wanted to.  Muggle-born students get a visit from a Hogwarts staff member, who explains the situation but this does not seem to be the case. Harry just received a letter. He cannot use the same owl that delivered the letter because the first letter was delivered like a normal one in the mail box.

Comment: Because JK Rowling doesn't know how to run a school. Or for an in-universe explanation, because the administrators of Hogwarts are idiots.

Comment: Out-of-universe this is the first introduction to one of the recurring themes of the series; wizard institutions are satires of the unthinking, inflexible, impersonal, occasionally corrupt, vulnerable to abuse, and always bureaucratic muggle institutions we're all familiar with. The fact that Harry has no ability to comply is a feature of the text there to introduce a theme; it's not a mistake.

Comment: I suppose a follow-up to this would be *how DID Hermione respond*? It's not mentioned in any of the answers below, either. Or any muggle-born, I suppose. Not a mention in any of the letters about "we will be sending someone to assist and who will prove to you that magic indeed exists and you shouldn't put your child on Ritalin or call the cops".

Comment: @Marakai While Harry was living with muggles, he's not himself muggle-born, so they likely used the 'wizard-born' enrolment process, rather than the muggle-born one that includes visits (like Hermione would have received).

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere Yes, but that still leaves me wondering: if you had someone showing up at your doorstep dressed like Dumbledore, or heavens forbid a half-giant like Hagrid, what, apart from something like an Obliviate spell would not have you freaking out and going "you're what? you want to take my child where? who and what are you?" - while your SO had run out the backdoor frantically calling the police.

Comment: The same way hermione(a muggle) replied to her letter.

Comment: @Arun not exactly. Muggle-born get a visit from Hogwarts staff member (example - Tom Riddle).  Harry did not (initially) get such a visit - just a letter.

Comment: Ritalin ftw.. :)

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Harry is a bit of a special case, since he was born to a witch and wizard (James and Lily Potter), but was raised by Muggles. It seems that he received the version of the letter intended for children born to witches and wizards (which he was). Those families would, of course, have an owl of their own or know where to go in order to send one.

Unlike regular Muggleborns, Hagrid doesn't turn up to explain the things that are normally explained to them, because Harry is assumed to already know all of those things. Hagrid is shocked (and then angry) when he learns that Harry doesn't know "anything". Hagrid is only sent when it becomes clear that Harry wasn't receiving his letters (though it's never explained how they knew that).

We know from Snape's memories in *Deathly Hallows* that letters sent via the Muggle post can reach Hogwarts, so for Muggle families written confirmation can be sent using a method they're already familiar with.

Comment: Good points. But, as per the question, if they were expecting an owl back why wouldn't they send the initial invite via owl as well?

Comment: I don't buy this for a second. Harry Potter was a legend in the wizarding community. *Everyone* knew his parents had been killed by He-Who-Must-Not-Be-Named. Even Hogwarts' own Headmaster had been carefully watching Harry be raised since the day he was sent to live with his muggle relatives.

Comment: @Dan, you underestimate the power of bureaucracy  :-)

Comment: @Dan Exactly. Harry Potter was a legend to the wizarding community. The very idea that he didn't know he was a wizard was unthinkable to them. How could you keep someone so amazing in the dark about who he is? Most wizards would assume he was well aware of his heritage.

Comment: @jpmc26 Hmm, that's a interesting perspective. He was so famous that nobody considered the fact that he might not know where to obtain an owl.

Comment: @Dan: I would expect that the Dursleys were given a lot of information that was supposed to be passed along to Harry as he grew up.  I don't think Harry would have had any trouble sending an owl if not for the Dursleys' horrid behavior.

Comment: In addition to  my comment to the original question: apart from showing up on a doorstep and casting a *believus magicus* on the parents just how was this supposed to work? Using a "magic doesn't exist" as the most likely baseline, most muggle parents would likely call the police. Even if someone as dignified as Minerva McGonagall showed up.

Comment: @Marakai We know how it works: Dumbledore’s visit to Tom Riddle shows it (even though he was also witch-born and so probably, by the logic in this answer, should also have received the standard letter like Harry did). You calmly tell them that there is such a thing as magic, and that their child shows signs of being capable of it; and when they disbelieve you, you show them evidence. A slightly more logic-based approach would likely be taken with parents than with 11-year-olds like Tom, but I see no reason it wouldn’t be essentially the same procedure.

Answer (score 18):

### He would've sent an owl from Diagon Alley.

Muggle-borns generally get a visit from a Hogwarts member of staff. Riddle got Dumbledore. Harry got Hagrid. The communication issue can probably be put down to a blunder on Hagrid's part. He probably should have just knocked on the door and asked to speak to Harry and explained the situation in person. However, he may have had some recollection of McGonagall's opinion of the Dursleys. Knowing that they are particularly Muggleish Muggles he may have decided that simply popping the letter through the letterbox was the wisest approach. When that failed, for reasons best known to himself, he decided to inundate the Dursleys with increasing quantities of letters.

As for how Muggle-borns traditionally signify their acceptance of an offer, they have to send an owl. This can be done from Diagon Alley. Of course, if a teacher presents their invitation in person then they can presumably accept there and then. The owl is just a written confirmation. The teacher would explain that the child has to go to Diagon Alley (with their parents, if necessary) to buy their school supplies.

> “Where do you buy spellbooks?” interrupted Riddle, who had taken the heavy money bag without thanking Dumbledore, and was now examining a fat gold Galleon.
>   “In Diagon Alley,” said Dumbledore. “I have your list of books and school equipment with me. I can help you find everything —”
>   <sub>*(Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 13, The Secret Riddle)*.</sub>

Even if the teacher doesn't offer to go with the student, as Dumbledore did, the Hogwarts letter itself contains the full list of required items. The teacher only needs to give the family details of how to get to Diagon Alley.

> “Still got yer letter, Harry?” he asked as he counted stitches.
>   Harry took the parchment envelope out of his pocket.
>   “Good,” said Hagrid. “There’s a list there of everything yeh need.”
>   Harry unfolded a second piece of paper he hadn’t noticed the night before, and read...
>   <sub>*(Philosopher's Stone, Chapter 5, Diagon Alley)*.</sub>

If the Dursleys were supportive of Harry's decision to go to Hogwarts (as the question suggests) then they presumably would've had no problem with taking him to Diagon Alley.

Once in Diagon Alley you can buy your own owl.

Or, if you don't want an owl, you can hire one from the post office. Diagon Alley presumably has an owl post office; Hogsmeade, which is rather smaller, has one after all.

> “Thanks,” said Harry, picking up a packet of tiny black Pepper Imps. “What’s Hogsmeade like? Where did you go?”
>   [...]
>   “The post office, Harry! About two hundred owls, all sitting on shelves, all color-coded depending on how fast you want your letter to get there!”
>   <sub>*(Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 8, The Flight of the Fat Lady)*.</sub>

Comment: The problem is that the letter didn't explain about Diagon Alley or how to get to there (iirc), so expecting that Harry or the Dursleys would know to go there is an oversight on the part of the letter.

Comment: @Xantec. You're right, it is. The Hogwarts staff member delivering the letter would be expected to mention Diagon Alley (as Dumbledore did). Hagrid neglected to do this by just posting the letter through the letterbox. So really it's an oversight on the part of Hagrid (although obviously in reality he did take Harry to DA in person).

Comment: "Muggle-borns generally get a visit from a Hogwarts staffer" Really, Tom Riddle and Harry Potter were very special cases. There's no evidence that *all* muggle-born students get a visit from a Hogwarts staffer, or even that *most* do.

Comment: @TylerH, what else do the staff have to do in the summer?

Comment: @TheDarkLord Live? Work? Research? What do school teachers in real life do in the summer?

Comment: Weren't the Dursleys a bit of a special case in that they *knew* magic existed, but wanted absolutely nothing to do with it?

Comment: @TylerH They are eligible to draw unemployment during the summer, if they aren't working.

Comment: @TylerH - They get their lives back after having sacrificed so much of them for other people's kids!

Comment: @TylerH They would go on holiday for part of the summer. But they might work for part of it too. Making sure new students know about the offer and reach the school is an important part of the intake process. I'm sure the staff would play their part in this, either before the summer holidays or during them.

Comment: @TylerH Harry was known to be a special case, yes; but what was special about Tom Riddle? At the time when Dumbledore visited him, he was a normal boy living in an orphanage whose name had been scribbled down by a magic device in a tower like so many others. There is no evidence that Dumbledore even knew beforehand whether he was full-blood, half-blood, or Muggle-born (why bother asking Mrs Cole about his parents if he did?), much less that there was anything special about him at all.

Comment: @TylerH JKR did say that a Hogwarts teacher usually visits the family of muggle-borns to explain the wisarding word: see the first quote in https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/47726/4918

Comment: @b_jonas Not quite; that quote says "special messengers", and makes no mention of teachers. "Special messenger" could just as well mean an owl delivering a longer/enchanted letter.

Comment: It seems like Dumbledore visited Riddle at the orphanage expecting a muggle born. Maybe they detected underage magic like they find out muggle borns. It is unlikely any of the Gaunts knew or had registered their names into Hogwarts. And Merope Gaunt died too soon to even let anyone know Voldemort's ancestry. If anyone had known who Voldemort was descended from(the Gaunts) they would have known he was from a magical ancestry.

Comment: It seems reasonable to infer that Diagon Alley has enchantments protecting it, and muggle parents wouldn't be able to just pop in to buy an owl, even if they did have instructions on how to do so.

Comment: @Acccumulation Well, Riddle was seemingly able to go and buy his stuff without being accompanied by a wizard. Allowing the select few wizarding Muggle-borns and their families to go and buy their stuff is part of allowing them into the wizarding world.

Comment: @TylerH Or it could be someone from the Ministry of Magic, instead of a Hogwarts teacher.  Perhaps from the [Muggle Liaison Office](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Muggle_Liaison_Office)?

Comment: @Chronocidal Yes, very possibly.

Answer (score 9):

### Petunia Dursley knows how to contact the school

In fact, she even managed to do so unprompted when she was young:

> "You didn't think it was such a freak's school when you wrote to the headmaster and begged him to take you."
>
> ...
>
> "Severus saw the envelope, and he couldn't believe a Muggle could have contacted Hogwarts, that's all! He says there must be wizards working undercover in the postal service who take care of —"
>
> <sub>*(Deathly Hallows, Chapter 33, The Prince's Tale)*.</sub>

Comment: Excellent point!

Comment: And she suggests contacting them again after Harry's letter comes.

Answer (score 5):

Another perspective, although @Anthony Grist's answer is a good one.

Several times in the series, we see letters sent by owl and replies written quickly and given back to the same owl. I know that the letter Harry read was given to him by Hagrid, but I doubt they changed the text from the original and subsequent letters, at least many of which were sent by owl. As unbiased readers, it seems unlikely that someone who had no idea about the wizarding world would then think to write a response and post it back *but* we have also seen many times that wizards don't always recognise their ways as unusual.

I think the possibility of writing a quick response "Yes, I would love to come, Yours, H. Potter," and sending it back with the original owl would be a real possibility in the minds of the senders of the letters.

Comment: This is actually what happens the morning after Hagrid shows up with Harry's letter -- the owl delivers the daily newspaper and then **waits** for payment. I'd assume an owl would be smart enough to wait for a "heck yeah" reply.

Comment: Might not fit with the months-in-advance closing date.

Comment: This doesn’t really fit with the fact that the first of Harry’s letters were delivered by regular Muggle post, rather than by owl.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet - Were they?

Comment: @ThruGog Well, they certainly arrive on the doormat together with their regular post. I admit, though, that I was getting them mixed up with the Weasleys’ holiday invitation to Harry, misremembering that the postman was involved here as well. You’re probably right that they were owl-delivered, at least from the third day on when they start stuffing themselves into downstairs toilets and chimneys to get through.

Comment: @Janus Bahs Jacquet - Yes, I was genuinely asking because it is unclear. I always sort of assumed owls somehow got them through the letter box but that's just odd!

Comment: Come to think of it, unless I’m misremembering, the movie actually shows and owl flying close to the door and dropping off the letter, which magically slips itself right through the letter box.

Answer (score 0):

This answer to another question may help:

[Who sent the letters](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10893/in-the-first-hp-book-who-sent-harry-thousands-of-the-same-letters?rq=1)

Apparently, Dumbledore had a feeling that contacting Harry might be difficult.

Granted, since he lived with Muggles who would not have an owl, it appears that this was either an oversight, or J.K. Rowling had a broader plan in mind when she wrote it that way. I suppose we'd have to find something she wrote to know for certain.  I wasn't able to find anything explaining it.

EDIT: Something she wrote explaining why the letters were not sent via owl.

Comment: I don't see anything in the post you links to that answers the question of how Harry was expected to reply.